# How to uninstall handlebars?

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js

While I am trying to uninstall handlebars I am getting this exception

> enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'package.json'

Comment: Sometimes it works to "install" it, then "uninstall" it.  The install might fix the issues that are preventing the uninstall.

Answer (score 0):

First check in package.json file that handlebars is listed in dependencies or not
.